# Multiple document.write not working

Tags: php, html

I have a remote script called `load.php` which is called with an argument `id`. This then appends the `id` to several links, and displays them on the page called `display.html` (which calls `load.php`).

However, **display.html only shows the first link**, and all other links are missing.

Code for `display.html`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.come/load.php?id=1"></script>
</head>
```

Code for `load.php`

```
<?php
$pid = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $pid = $_GET['id'];
}
?>
var firstlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="firstimage.jpg" alt="First Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
document.write(firstlink);

var secondlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader2.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="secondimage.jpg" alt="Second Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
document.write(secondlink);

var thirdlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader3.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="thirdimage.jpg" alt="Third Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
document.write(thirdlink);
```

EDIT : Accidentally gave same links in all 3 loaders. They are 3 different links.

Comment: *Don't* use `document.write`!  Wait until the DOM is ready, then append your elements to the `<body>` (or wherever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* be using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)!  There are better tools for this.

What you should be doing is using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild), [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML), or just simply writing to [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) to add your elements - after waiting for the DOM to be ready, that is.

Here's a simple way to solve this problem:

```
<?php
$pid = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $pid = $_GET['id'];
}
?>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var firstlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="firstimage.jpg" alt="First Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
    window.document.body.innerHTML += firstlink;


    var secondlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="secondimage.jpg" alt="Second Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
    window.document.body.innerHTML += secondlink;


    var thirdlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="thirdimage.jpg" alt="Third Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
    window.document.body.innerHTML += thirdlink;
});
```

Comment: Just tried this! Continues to show only the first one. Also if I may, is there any specific reason not to use `document.write`? Also am I correct to say that `secondlink` and `thirdlink` need to be appended to the `innerHTML`, and not `firstlink` each time?

Comment: @SainathKrishnan: Oh yes... `firstlink` shouldn't have been appended each time.  That was a typo.  Try it now.

Comment: @SainathKrishnan: As for `document.write()`, it's bad practice.  You can't easily control where the elements are being added.  In your case, your script is in the `<head>`, so it's adding your links there.  Also, if you *ever* call `document.write` after the page is loaded, it will erase everything on your page before writing what you told it to.  It's better practice to use `innerHTML` is all.

Comment: I did it with the right links as well, still continues to show me only the very first link. Changing the order of the links makes the topmost link appear, but all others continue to remain invisible

Comment: @SainathKrishnan: Then you probably have some other CSS or JavaScript that's hiding your links.

Comment: Aside from making the links a bit generic, the code is exactly the same. There is no extra code anywhere!

Comment: @SainathKrishnan: Works fine for me (http://jsbin.com/xicoregoqu/1/edit)... Don't know what else to tell ya.

Comment: Appending your code before my `document.write` block works! If I substitute my links into your code, it stops working.. (This is keeping in mind that the links work when displayed individually)

Comment: For some reason, when I used the code from your `jsbin`, it began to work! Anyway, thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

After the first `document.write()` the whole content of the webpage is overwritten and the script is aborted.

Use the following:

```
var firstlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="firstimage.jpg" alt="First Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';


var secondlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="secondimage.jpg" alt="Second Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';


var thirdlink='<a href="http://www.example.com/loader.html?parameter=<?php echo $pid?>"><img src="thirdimage.jpg" alt="Third Link!" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';

document.write(firstlink + secondlink + thirdlink);
```

Comment: `document.write` only wipes the page if it was closed.  In this case, the `document.write` is running in the head, so the document is still open.

Comment: You're still putting `<a>` tags in the `<head>`, so that's still not quite right.

Comment: I just helped the OP to achieve what he wanted, if it makes sense or not is another question.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately none of them appear when I did. I am able to use `document.write` on each one individually, but when concatenating, it remains blank.